# What does parenthesis mean in SELECT (COLNAME) mysql

Tags: mysql

I am reviewing somebody's code and came across this sort of select syntax:

```
SELECT (Test_ID) id, (Test_Host) host, (Test_Port) port
FROM Test_Connection
```

I can tell what the parenthesis do here it probably means `SELECT Test_ID AS id` but is there an advantage or disadvantage using above versus using `AS` ?

Comment: That is just a different syntax. It complies to the same.

Comment: `As` is completely optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. It means `Select Column_Name AS Alias`. This is an odd coding style, probably representing level of someone's understaning of SQL. There is no harm in removing parenthisis. Just keep all code similar.

Using `AS` is voulantary, but together with indentation results in code that is easier to read.

Parenthesys are used to set operations order for expressons. For single columns they are redundant, but does not cause any errors as syntax analyser will drop them anyway. This style produces confusing and harder to read code.

Comment: To someone, who has no clue of SQL syntax - yes. And is you like to type unnecessary symbols too.

Comment: yes, and you may bring confusion when someone else is reading the code (as you right now)

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses do nothing.  They are simply placing an expression in parentheses, and that expression consists of a single column name.

It is much preferable to use `as` for defining column alaises:

```
SELECT Test_ID as id, Test_Host as host, Test_Port as port
FROM Test_Connection;
```

To understand the reason, consider these two select clauses:

```
SELECT Test_ID, Test_Host, Test_Port
SELECT Test_ID Test_Host, Test_Port
```

The first returns three columns, the second only two.  The missing comma can be rather hard to spot and lead to debugging problems.

I will admit that putting the column expressions in parentheses also solves this problem (parentheses are not allowed for the aliases).  However, you might as well use standard practices for your coding.